# Laravel 5.4 AJAX form post routing 404 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I am working on my form submitting with AJAX. Form was working before with just regular method without AJAX. All routes is good, and form working properly.  Now I found need in AJAX functions to submit my form. I've wrote script as usual for AJAX submitting.

Here is my form script:

```
       <div class="onpage-sold-input">
            {!! Form::open(['url' => route('sold.sold'),'class'=>'contact-form', 'id'=>'search-sold-button','method'=>'POST']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('sold', old('sold'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Qty.')) !!}
                <input type="hidden" name="part_id" value="{{ $inventory->id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                {!! Form::button('Sold', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-success', 'id'=>'sold-button','type'=>'submit']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
```

Hare is AJAX script:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
}
});

$('#sold-button').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var form = $('#search-sold-button'),
    data = form.serialize(),
    ajax_url = 'sold/sold',
    alert_section = $('.alert-section');

$.post(ajax_url, data, function (resp) {
    alert_section.fadeIn().find('.alert').html(resp);
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert_section.fadeOut();
    }, 3000)
})
});
```

Here is route:

```
Route::post('/sold/sold',['uses'=>'PriceController@sold', 'as'=>'sold.sold']);
```

And this is the error that I am getting in console:

```
POST http://localhost/backend_master/public/inventory/sold/sold 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:
`ajax_url = 'sold/sold',`

by this:
`ajax_url = form.attr('action'),`

;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php artisan route:list` command to list available routes. If you are using resource for object then the your route name for saving sold object will be `sold.store`.

If you are not usre about route name then don't use route() function in form action attribute, use url("sold") and method="post",

But in your ajax code do the following changes

```
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#sold-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#search-sold-button'),
        data = form.serialize(),
        ajax_url = {! url('sold/sold' !},
        alert_section = $('.alert-section');

        $.post(ajax_url, data, function (resp) {
        alert_section.fadeIn().find('.alert').html(resp);
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert_section.fadeOut();
        }, 3000)
        })
    });
```

**Changes**

If your route is `sold/sold` then use `{! route('sold/sold')!}` or `{! url('sold/sold') !}`